# Is it possible to view release notes for previous app versions as an admin or developer in app store connect?

Tags: app-store-connect

As a developer, I would like to be able to click through previous releases of my app and see what I entered in the "whats new in this update" box, however App Store connect only seems to show the currently-published release and the current upcoming/in-review release (if there is one). I can't seem to see previous versions in that list, and to the extent that I can access metadata about previous builds though other sections of the UI, this metadata doesn't include what I typed into the "whats new" box when submitting the new release.

Are my release notes for all previous versions of my app completely lost, or is there a way to access these old release notes?

Comment: Have you thought about using the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparrently, while this information does not seem to be available to developers or admins through App Store Connect, it is (at the time of this answer) available on the public web version of the app's page of the app store.

To see it, navigate to your apps listing (the url starts with https://apps.apple.com/us/app) and scroll down to "whats new".
Next to "whats new" you'll see a version history link
[image: the "whats new" heading with the version history link next to it]

Clicking this should show the release notes for every version of the app that was published to the store.

Comment: While not a dev, I am always interested in release notes and was hoping you (or another person)  found something like what you were asking for.  Thanks and +1 x2 for the detective work!

Comment: Some credit should also go to @thinkr for the idea to use the wayback machine - it was in looking at the page through there that I realized I didnt actually need the wayback machine and that I was just failing to check all the different places release notes could be